# Dirac's gammas in scalar Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices

**Can one write a Lagrangian for a scalar field using Dirac's gamma matrices? If so, is it useful?**
This question came to my mind when trying to write a general (nonrenormalizable) Lagrangian for a scalar field, which has the form
$$\mathcal{L}(\varphi)=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\varphi\partial^\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\varphi^2-\sum_{k,n}\frac{C_{k,n}}{\Lambda^{n+k-4}}\partial^n\varphi^k$$
with a $\varphi\rightarrow -\varphi$ symmetry. Obviously, for symmetry reasons, terms with $k$ odd are absent.But what about $n$ odd? Can one have a term like
$$\frac{C_{4,1}}{\Lambda^1}\varphi^3\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\varphi$$
with the odd derivative summed with a Dirac's gamma?

My intuition is that no, it can't work, because gamma matrices have spinor indices (and a scalar field doesn't) but this doesn't seem like a satisfying explanation to me.

Comment: Hint: representations under the Poincaré group.

Comment: How is that term supposed to be something you can integrate over as a Lagrangian density? The $\gamma^\mu$ is a matrix - unless it is sandwiched between a spinor and a conjugate spinor so that the result is a number, this just isn't a number.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Kemmer-Duffin equation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffin%E2%80%93Kemmer%E2%80%93Petiau_algebra#Duffin%E2%80%93Kemmer%E2%80%93Petiau_equation